# How to read sys.stdin containing binary data in python (ignore errors)?

Tags: python, file, encoding, stdin

How do I read `sys.stdin`, but ignoring decoding errors?
I know that `sys.stdin.buffer` exists, and I can read the binary data and then decode it with `.decode('utf8', errors='ignore')`, but I want to read `sys.stdin` line by line.
Maybe I can somehow reopen the `sys.stdin` file but with `errors='ignore'` option?

Comment: what about putting the decode inside a try and handling the decoding errors as exceptions?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki, how it can help? I need to do `sys.stdin.read()`, or more specifically `for line in sys.stdin`, but it throws a UnicodeDecodeError. If I catch it, how can I read the line anyway? I just need to ignore symbols it can't read. The line mostly contains ascii characters, but it can contain characters outside the ASCII, so I need to just ignore them or replace with '?' for example

Comment: If you cannot decode it you have to see why. give us an example of the input that is giving you the decode error. Maybe some inputs are encoded in another format, we need some examples to see how to solve it

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki, data doesn't matter, I want to expect any data, including pure binary data (even often it's text), I don't want to be able to decode all the data, I want to be able to ignore the data I can't decode using `bytes.decode` function. I could do it if I was reading actual file like `open(filename, 'r', errors='ignore')`, but I want to read `sys.stdin` instead, but it's already an opened file descriptor, so I don't know how to set the `errors='ignore'` option.

Comment: then you put a `try` and inside you decode the data and a `except` with a `pass` that will just ignore the data that fails to decode

Comment: Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/q/50476200/2836621

Comment: You can also read `sys.stdin.buffer` line by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found three solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50476200/changing-the-way-stdin-stdout-is-opened-in-python-3) as Mark Setchell mentioned.

```
import sys
import io

def first():
    with open(sys.stdin.fileno(), 'r', errors='ignore') as f:
        return f.read()

def second():
    sys.stdin = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdin.buffer, errors='ignore')
    return sys.stdin.read()

def third():
    sys.stdin.reconfigure(errors='ignore')
    return sys.stdin.read()


print(first())
#print(second())
#print(third())
```

Usage:

```
$ echo 'a\x80b' | python solution.py
ab
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set an errorhandler option on the [PYTHONIOENCODING](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING) environment variable: this will affect both `sys.stdin` and `sys,stdout` (`sys.stderr` will always use "backslashreplace").  `PYTHONIOENCODING` accepts an optional encoding name and an optional errorhandler name preceded by a colon, so "UTF8", "UTF8:ignore" and ":ignore" would all be valid values.

```
$  cat so73335410.py
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = sys.stdin.read()
    print(data)
$
$  echo hello | python so73335410.py
hello

$  echo hello hello hello hello | zip > hello.zip
  adding: - (deflated 54%)
$
$  cat hello.zip | PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF8:ignore python so73335410.py
UYv>
  -▒
UY  HW@'PKv>

  ▒-PK,-/>PKmPK/>
$
```